# What can be reason of showing Blog post columns like this?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[image]

When I add blog posts via plugin into the home page columns are showing in this way. I assume the problem is with theme files since all similar plugins are giving the same issue. What can cause such trouble? Why some columns are empty?

Comment: The variable heights of the image/text would likely cause this. Assuming the layout is not using a masonry/isotope JS layout library.

Comment: The plugin also had a turn off masonry but the result was the same.

Comment: Difficult to advise further without a reduced test case link old chap.

Comment: You'll have to dive in and use some CSS to solve this then. Make sure the 3rd, 5th, 7th, etc. post have an "clear: left;". To be more precise, every odd. Like: .your-container-class > div:nth-child(odd){ clear: left; } or something that matches your DOM structure.